# How to split a number with leading zeroes into separate digits in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anyone know a way to split 12 digit number into separate digits starting from 0 using Excel.

Example :012345678901 is split as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...

I've use this formula `=MID($A1,column()-1,1)` but it is unable to read the 1st digit 0. It keeps appearing as 1,2,3,4,5,... instead of 0,1,2,3,4,5,... and also if there is a number starting with 00.

Is there any formula that its able to read 0 or 00 as the first number followed by the rest?

Comment: Is the leading zero showing in the original cell?  It sounds like Excel is treating it as a number instead of text.  As a number, there's no leading zero.  You can guarantee it's treated as text by starting the entry with an apostrophe.

Comment: Excel numbers don't show leading zeros. If you want leading zeros, you need text not numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your number is being treated as a number instead of text.  My guess that you have that column formatted as text.  Try using the following to force Excel to treat that text as text instead of a number:

```
=MID($A1 & "", COLUMN() - 1, 1)
```

The only change I made was to add the `& ""`.  This concatenates an empty string to the value in A1 and that forces Excel to treat it as text instead of a number.

Comment: This won't help if Excel handled the original input as a number.  The leading zeros will already be gone and converting back to text won't restore them.

Comment: Indeed.  But judging by the question, he already has them set up and displaying the leading zeroes.  That's why I assume he has that column formatted as text.

Comment: If I enter the number with the leading apostrophe, Excel treats it as text, but if I enter it into a column formatted as text, Excel keeps the leading zero, but the formula treats it as a number.

Comment: I use LO Calc, and with that, the string functions work correctly if the cell was formatted as text. So I assumed the same behavior in Excel. I just cranked up an old Excel 2007, and the string functions work correctly there, also.  So I'm not able to replicate Excel treating a text entry as a number.

Answer (score 1):

The formula works only for text values, as explained in the comments above.

A1 has text with a leading zero, A2 has a number and Excel does not show leading zeros for numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes leading zeros are there only as a result of formatting, for example:

[image]

This can explain the mismatch between the value in the cell and the value in the Formula Bar.

You can convert this into a twelve character string by using this short **U**ser **D**efined **F**unction:

```
Public Function txet(r As Range) As String
   txet = r.Text
End Function
```

It is used like:

[image]